# Why is there extra white space in a table cell when text wraps?

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontally centered `div` with two children. Each of the children are centered vertically with `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`

Everything works fine when the screen (or parent container) is wide enough for all the text to be on one line. However, if the screen/parent shrinks, then the text wraps and leaves a large amount of white space.  Why doesn't the div shrink to fit the text?

The image below shows the problem.  Everything is the way I want it in the top image.  The grey section wraps the content, and is centered within its parent container.  However, if the parent shrinks so the text wraps, a bunch of white space is left over (see the area highlighted in the red rectangle).  This whitespace creates the illusion that the whole element is aligned left instead of centered.

A jsFiddle example with what I have so far is here: http://jsfiddle.net/eterpstra/pRgeL/1/

Any way to get rid of this whitespace so everything appears *more* centered, instead of shifted to the left?

[image]

Comment: You could use `text-align: center;` and maybe change some of the padding

Comment: Have you tried removing the padding from `.site-title`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills text-align: center has the same problem, too much whitespace, but this time on each end.

Comment: @SimonAdcock Yes, I've tried that. There is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

As @andi writes, browsers do table layout in a bit odd way. This can be demonstrated using just a single-cell table in HTML:

```
<div style="width: 270px; background: yellow">
<table>
<tr><td style="font-size: 25px; border: solid 1px">Way too much white space
</table>
</div>
```

Browsers try first to set all the text on the same line, allocating the available width (here 270px), then find out that the text needs to be wrapped, but then forget to tune down the cell width according to the length of the longest line of the content.

Putting a `<br>` tag in the content (at the point(s) where the line will be broken) would “fix” this, but it would be poor design, very inflexible, to use fixed line breaks that way.

It seems that this can be fixed by using an inner `span` element inside the cell and setting the `style.width` property of the cell to equal the `offsetWidth` property of the `span` element, with the unit `px` appended:

```
<div style="width: 270px; background: yellow">
<table>
<tr><td id=cell style="font-size: 25px; border: solid 1px"><span id=t>Way too much white
  space</span>
</table>
</div>
<script>
 document.getElementById('cell').style.width = 
   document.getElementById('t').offsetWidth + 'px';
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yucca42/MfcdB/)

For a general solution, I suppose you could – instead of specific coding like the above – write a script that traverses the `td` elements (or elements shown with `display: table-cell`) that may need fixing, insert a `span` element dynamically, and then do the fix. Something like this, assuming, for definiteness, that your table cells are all `td` elements and have content that can safely be wrapped in in `span` elements:

```
<script>
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  var cell = cells[i];
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = cell.innerHTML;
  cell.innerHTML = span.outerHTML;
}
for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  var cell = cells[i];
  cell.style.width = cell.childNodes[0].offsetWidth + 'px';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the browser increases the width of that gray part (.header-wrap) until it is 100% of the width of .header (which you set in the CSS).  If the text in .header-wrap is still too long, it will wrap, but the width of .header-wrap will stay at the full width rather than shrinking to fit.  Which makes sense, I think.

I'd say your best bet is to use `text-align: center;` and just don't worry about the extra white space.  I don't think there's anything you can do about it in this exact situation.